# Найти все натуральные числа, которые делятся на каждую из своих цифр

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Задача - найти все натуральные числа, не превосходящие заданное число N и делящиеся нацело на каждую из своих цифр
Дошел до такого кода:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Enter n: ";
    cin >> n;
    int n1 = n;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int length = 0;
        while (n != 0) {                    //Узнаем длину числа
            length++;
            n /= 10;
        }
        int *mas = new int[length];
        while (n1 != 0) {
            mas[i] = n1 % 10;               //добавляем цифры числа в массив
            n1 /= 10;
        }

        bool t = true;

        for (int a = 0; a < length; a++) {
            if (i%mas[a] != 0) {
                t = false;                      //проверяем, делится или нет
            }
        }
        if (t == true) {
            cout << i<< " ";
        }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Но всё равно не работает. В чём проблема?

Comment: Некоторые цифры - нули...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как-то уж очень сложно у вас...

```
bool test(int i)
{
    bool dig[9] = {false};
    int k = i;
    while(k)
    {
        int d = k%10;
        k /= 10;
        if (d == 0 || dig[d-1]) continue;
        dig[d-1] = true;
        if (i%d) return false;
    }
    return true;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        if (test(i)) cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Это если хочется сэкономить на проверках и не проверять дважды одну и ту же цифру, но для реальных чисел это особой роли не играет, так что сократить можно до

```
bool test(int i)
{
    int k = i;
    while(k)
    {
        int d = k%10;
        k /= 10;
        if (d && i%d) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `if (i == 0) return false`. `if (d == 0 || i%d) return false`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n;
  int i = 1;
  cout << "Введите число n";
  cin >> n;
  while (i <= n) # Не превосходящее n
  {
    int test_num = 0;
    long double indexx = 0; 
    string s = to_string(i); # Перевод в строку, чтобы знать длинну
    while (test_num != s.length()) # Перебор всех цифр числа
      {
        long double l =  i / pow(10,indexx); # Возведение в степень
        int m = fmod(l,10); # Деление с отстатком от возведенного числа
        if (m == 0) # Если цифра равна 0, то делить ненадо
        {
          test_num += 1;
          indexx += 1;
          continue;
        }
        else if (i % m == 0 and m != 0) 
        {
          test_num += 1;
          indexx += 1;
          continue;
        }
        else break;
      }  
    if (test_num == s.length()) # Проверка, все ли цифры поделились
    {
      cout << i << endl;
    }
    i += 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: На самом деле сам только начал прогать на плюсах, но я считаю данный способ лучше подходит для новичков.

Comment: А теперь сравните размер своего кода с кодом в ответе выше

Comment: Как я и сказал выше, этот код по своей концепции мне кажется проще, я не стремился укоротить свой код.

Comment: Вот это -- `long double l =  i / pow(10,indexx);       int m = fmod(l,10);` (я уже молчу, что комментарий эт `//` а не `#`) вообще зачем? Ведь у вас уже **есть все цифры** в строке`s`. (Но если сейчас учат так, что вам проще понимать подобный код, то плохи наши дела...)